# what is the maximum file size that I can transfer from Could storage to BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to transfer 2 years data from Campaign Manager to GCS bucket. Looks like it has been transferred. But I'm not sure the data range of the file as I'm unable to open it. Is there any size limit to transfer from CM to bucket to Bigquery?

Answer (score 0):

`Transfer Service` has no limitations regarding file sizes as you can see in this page [enter link description here](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/quotas). You should be able to transfer all your files without any problems.

About `BigQuery`, as you can see in this [page](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas), there are some limitations regarding file size. As you can see in the print below, your `load job` can not have more than **15 TB** and each individual file can not be bigger than **5 GB**

[image]